# PDO Php , как записать в переменную чтобы передать ниже параметры

Tags: php, pdo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста , как записать запрос на переменную чтобы передать параметры ниже ( PDO ). Пробовал $user->execute($sql); и тд , нулевой пишет ошибка

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

строка   `$arrResult = $pdo->fetchAll()` возвращает вам массив пользователей с указанными логином и паролем.  Поскольку маловероятно, что в ответах будет более одной записи, то испозовать следует просто `fetch()`. который вернет одну строку или ничего. Эта строка и будет искомым `user` объектом.
Чтобы получить имена полей а не индексы используется параметр `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

в общем должно получиться что-то вроде

```
 $user = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if($user){
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
 }
```

*Обратите также внимание, что лучше в запросе явно перечислить необходимые поля, а не использовать `*`.*

Comment: Не знаете ли в чем может быть проблема , при успешном входе в учетную запись нету отображении данных - параметров user . Хотя в HTML вписаны php сессии в теги

Comment: @АнтонЗырянов `session_start` не вызывается мб?

Comment: В файле , в начале прописано session_start() , но не вызывается

Comment: Ниже отправил , в двух файлах session прописана